# Display header of fragment as Activity footer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with 2 fragments A and B.. The fragment B is displayed below A and it's sticked to the footer of the activity. Now, this fragment B should expand on touch and fill the whole activity.. So, lets say my fragment B has (on it's design) one header to display some info. I want only this header to be the part that is displayed from the fragment B when this is still working as a footer of the initial activity.

Something like Google's Play Music app as you can see in the images (where the fragment B is the now playing info that expands):

(state 1 - fragment B as footer) http://s30.postimg.org/mn6sdm2u9/Screenshot_2015_12_07_23_27_05_com_google_androi.png

(state 2 - fragment B doing fill animation)
http://s30.postimg.org/5nxtycrmp/Screenshot_2015_12_07_23_26_56_com_google_androi.png

(state 3 - fragment B filling the whole area)
http://s30.postimg.org/roirspzoh/Screenshot_2015_12_07_23_27_13_com_google_androi.png

I've been searching on how to display only some part of the fragment's layout content but I don't seem to find many specific information on this, so I need some help here.

I must also say that I'm only assuming that the Google is doing this with fragments, anyway, I would appreciate if someone corrects me if I'm wrong or if there's a better way to do this with no fragments..

Comment: You can make it like drawer layout. Although, it seems, I saw already exisiting layout for it. Now, if I found then post to you.

Comment: Maybe it [GitHub Flipboard](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet)

Comment: And this [Sliding Panel](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2294). It is that you want.

Comment: That Sliding Panel, that's exactly it! Thanks, I also end up finding [this](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) :)

Comment: I'm glad that can help you! I already found a lot of similar views too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. There are many ways implement what you want. You can customize any view to overlay antoher. Here is a library to implement easily. Stick it to bottom and add some offset (header you mean)

https://github.com/wunderlist/android-sliding-layer-lib

Comment: thanks, I end up finding other useful links too, but I'll see which suits better :).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement what you want. You can customize any view to overlay antoher. Here is a library you can implement easily.

https://github.com/wunderlist/android-sliding-layer-lib